# What happens if Google Apps Script sends to many emails to fast?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I have a spreadsheet that utilizes a lot of Google Apps Script to manage and understand user input. The spreadsheet is used to record and monitor Chromebook checkouts to students and staff in a school.

When Chromebooks become overdue, the script sends me an email with information about the Chromebook and the checkout.

It also emails me information about when the Chromebook was checked back in. It works 90% of the time, however sometimes when staff delete too many entries to fast, I get emails for the first few, and the rest of the emails never come through. The emails tend to stop coming through for a long time afterward as well. In the executions list, it shows that all of the executions of the script finished successfully.

Does google set limitations on the amount of emails that can be sent within a specific amount of time?

Comment: You should try using Lock Service.  What can happen, is that subsequent instances of the script start running before the previous one has finished.  This can cause variable values to be overwritten, as each new instance of the script starts running before the previous one has finished.  Lock Service prevents a new instance of the function from running until the lock is released.  Make sure to have error handling and release the lock in the error handling if there is an error.  From the code editor, choose "Help" and "Documentation" and search "Lock"

Comment: Thanks. I have been wondering about this. This explains a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of emails that an user can send in a day.
Specific quota information is available on the quota tab of the Apps Script dashboard: https://script.google.com/dashboard

Comment: Thank you for this link. I have been looking for something like this to answer some of my questions about the apps script emailing function.